# Арифметическая операция с ALU

Tags: ассемблер

не совсем уверен, есть ли здесь знающие люди, но все же.
Если мне нужно с помощью ALU произвести операцию ~B + A
Могу ли я утверждать, что это A - B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. При использовании т.н. дополнительного кода  (Two's complement) для представления отрицательных чисел

```
-B = ~B + 1
```

Пример

```
   1            not 1     not 1 + 1 
00000001 =>  11111110 => 11111111   ===  -1
```

Так что чуть подправьте

Comment: Ну в принципе это то, что я и думал. Огромное спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Галочка слева помечает ответ как решение.

Comment: Нет, все таки ещё я не достиг полного понимания. В схеме, данной преподавателем. Перевод в доп код это отдельная автоматическая операция. Моя же задача в том, чтобы дополнить ALU чем-то, чтобы я смог реализовать операцию (A+B)&(~B+A) и меня терзают сомнения, насчёт вот этого ~B, означает ли это простое отрицание(инверсия) или же это действительно -B

Comment: Значит, нужно знать, как представлены отрицательные числа в вашей модели АЛУ. В абсолютном большинстве современных реальных процессоров код дополнительный, в него ничего переводить не надо. `смог реализовать операцию (A+B)&(~B+A)` в таком случае надо знать набор базовых операций - что, инверсии нет?

Comment: Ну скорее вопрос в другом. Что в таком уравнении представляет ~В: ~B или же-В

Comment: Ну как... Если стоит знак тильды, то битовая инверсия и есть. При использовании **обратного** кода код для представления отрицательных `~B = -B`, при использовании дополнительного (а также прямого) кода - как я уже написал - нет.